# Replace some substring with html tags

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Hi I have a string as shown:

```
var testStr = 'Soft is a texture, I am soft spoken and I like softy ice cream';
```

Want to add 'span' tags around word 'soft':
So result could be:

```
<span class='add-some-style'>Soft</span> is a texture, I am <span class='add-some-style'>soft</span> spoken and I like <span class='add-some-style'>soft</span>y ice cream
```

Tried string.replace, but with no success.

Comment: could you show the code you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex to replace. Do a global search while ignoring the case. Substitute the matched pattern along with extra tags.

```js
var testStr = 'Soft is a texture, I am soft spoken and I like softy ice cream';
var strVariable = 'soft'
var regexValue = new RegExp( `(${strVariable})`, 'ig');
const newStr = testStr.replace(regexValue, "<span class='add-some-style'>$1</span>");

console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if I want variable in regex, then?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex & string replace

```js
var testStr = 'Soft is a texture, I am soft spoken and I like softy ice cream';
const newStr = testStr.replace(/^Soft/gi, '<span class="highlight">Soft</span>');

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = newStr;
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

Comment: Have accepted one answer but increased points for all the answers, they gave insight for me to think. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the html every-time you find the soft keyword and then use concatenation to get your result

```js
var testStr = 'Soft is a texture, I am soft spoken and I like softy ice cream';
let index = 0;
let acc = '';
const wordLength = 4;

while (index >= 0) {
  const softWord = testStr.substr(index, wordLength);
  const preText = testStr.substring(0, index);
  acc += preText + '<span class="add-some-style:>' + softWord + '</span>';
  testStr = testStr.substring(index + wordLength);
  index = testStr.toLowerCase().indexOf('soft')
}
console.log(acc + testStr)
```